# Change MS Power Point file default layout when opening ppt files

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When open a ppt file in Power Point 2010, there is a "add notes" box on the bottom, which is usually blank. Most of time, I only read other's slides, and the notes is blank. I was wondering if there's any way to close the notes box by default when opening a ppt file. That way the main slide size is larger since it can extend to full height of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `file - options - advanced - display - open all documents using this view - select normal - slide only` or whatever view you'd like that doesn't have notes.